# createuserwizard is not automatically logging in the registered user

Tags: asp.net

I am using createuserwizard to register the users for the website. When the user is registered, it is not automatically logging-in the user. The user has to click on sign-in again to login. I set the property "LoginCreatedUser" to true but still it is not working. Please let me know if I am missing any settings.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I added the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthcookie(username, true) and it worked.

Comment: You should go ahead and accept your answer so this question falls off the "not answered" searches.